# Python dictionary reference returning something strange

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

I have a list of python dictionaries called `checkout_items`, created by a simple function (further simplified here, for ease of reading):

```
def checkout_items(request):
    items = get_cart_items(request)
    co_items = [] #a list of dictionaries to be used by the cart
    #iterate through the items and homogenize them into a standardized checkout_item format
    for i in items:
            co_item = {'number': num, 
                       'name': i.name, 
                       'sku': i.sku, 
                       'quantity': i.quantity, 
                       'price': i.price}
```

I reference this list elsewhere in a view (again, simplified):

```
    checkout_items = cart.checkout_items(request)

    attributes = {}
    for i in checkout_items:
        attributes['item_name_'+ str(i['number'])] = str(i['name'])
        attributes['item_number_'+ str(i['number'])] = str(i['sku'])
        attributes['quantity_'+ str(i['number'])] = str(i['quantity'])
```

But the name variable is being set to this: `<bound method CartItem.name of <CartItem: CartItem object>`

Yet the sku (alphanumeric string, just like "name") comes through just fine, it seems.  Both are coming directly from MySQL.  Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Show the models.py and more code, please

Comment: You most likely have a model method named `name` which could be overriding the mysql field. Can you show the model code for `CarItem` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<bound method CartItem.name of <CartItem: CartItem object>
```

is an error usually given when you are calling to see if a method is there, not actually calling the method itself. I would try adding `()` so `i.name()`

Comment: Both you and zmo were right, I was foolishly failing to call the method appropriately.  I have a moderately passable excuse as to why I was doing this, but my code should never have allowed for the misunderstanding in the first place.  Either way, you answered first, so I accepted your response.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

as you say, the data you give to the function `checkout_items()` is from get_cart_items().

So `items` is not a stupid namespace-like object, but an object that has methods that you wrote, and all of them are `CartItem`s.

Then when you build co_item, you give `i.name` to the dictionary, that is later printed out as `bound method CartItem.name of <CartItem: CartItem object>`.

It looks like your `CartItem` object has a method name! You should try `i.name()`. Or use whatever property that really has the name if `name()` is something else.